# need to remove & make URL shorten by using htaccess in full website

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-shortener

My present URL is :

- https://www.example.com/urlvalue1/urlvalue2/urlvalue3/urlvalue4/urlvalue5

I need to remove  **urlvalue3/urlvalue4/** from my URL all over the website.

How can I achieve this using .htaccess ?

presently in .htaccess I am using :

```
   RewriteRule ^((!/index/cslug/).+)$ /index/cslug/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: please post what you have tried

Comment: RewriteRule ^((!/index/cslug/).+)$ /index/cslug/$1 [L,NC]  @Starkeen

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/.+/.+/(.+)$ /index/cslug/$1/$2/$3 [L,NC]` (Based on your URL pattern)

Comment: @Juno_okyo your pattern will never match because there is a leading slash.

Comment: @Starkeen thank you! I was edited.

Answer (score 0):

The regex where you have `(!` should instead be: `(?!` for it to work as a negative lookahead:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!/index/cslug/).+)$ /index/cslug/$1 [L,NC]
```

next, to replace a 5 part URL:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2/$3 [R,L]
```